# Symfony Sonata setup 'make_homepage' route not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

I am attempting to install and configure Symfony CMF with the Sonata CMS by following the documentation. For the most part I have got it working except for the very last part where you add a button to the edit page so you can mark as page for use as the main index.

I have been following through the documentation and made the changes listed here: http://symfony.com/doc/1.2/cmf/tutorial/make-homepage.html but I seem to keep hitting the error below.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route 'make_homepage' not found") in SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig at line 34.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, and if so how did you get around it?

Comment: Had exactly the same problem. Seemed to be solved when I followed the answer below with the following changes: ```_cms_annotation:
    resource: "@[whatever-your-bundle-is-called]/Controller/"
    type: annotation```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that point you use @Route, you must put this in config/routing.yml

```
_cms_annotation:
    resource: @AcmeBasicCmsBundle/Controller/
    type:   annotation
```